# Returning arrays from php with ajax and json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

-I have an array that contains more arrays in my php file. I am sending a integer variable (Possibly something else for sometime later that isn't the problem)

-I want php file to return array according to the incoming variable (in this example just 1 and 2.)

-I tried somethings from other posts but they were too complicated and I couldn't understand any of them. And I want to be able to change it whenever I want.

This is what I have done so far..

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
var sayac = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).delegate("#klikme", "click", function() {
        $.post('sayac.php',{"komut": sayac }, function(data){

            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#output').html(res.result[0]);
            $('#output2').html(res.result[1]);
        });
        sayac = sayac + 1;
        if(sayac > 2)
            sayac = 1;
    });
});
</script>
<div id = "klikme">
    KLİK ME!
</div>

<div id = "output">
<?php include 'sayac.php'?>

</div>

<div id = "output2">

</div>
```

sayac.php

```
<?php 

    $returnThis = array( array("One" => "Sample Stuff Bla Bla this is one!","Two" => "Sample Text One"), 
                        array("One" => "Sample Stuff Bla Bla this is one!", "Two"=> "Sample Text Two"));

    if(isset($_POST["komut"]))
    {
        switch($_POST["komut"])
        {
            case 1:
                echo json_encode($returnThis[0]) ;
                break;
            case 2:
                echo json_encode($returnThis[1]); 
                break;
            default:
                echo "Something is wrong";
                break;
        }
    }

?>
```

**I want to return array and in my index I want to fill each of my output div areas with returned array's indexes but these doesn't work**

Comment: Echo the jsons inside your switch

Comment: You didn't explain what problem you are facing?

Comment: That was emberessing... Fixed it. **Didn't work**. I still can't get any response.

Comment: Yes sorry. I edited my question. @anant-kumar-singh

Comment: The problem is in the PHP or the JS? You should focus your question on the problematic issue

Comment: I don't know the issue? Explain please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your stuff like below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

$(document).ready(function() {
var sayac = 1;
    $(document).delegate("#klikme", "click", function() {
        $.post('sayac.php',{"komut": sayac }, function(data){

            var res = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(res); // since response is an object so you cannot access in the way that you did.
            $('#output').html(res.One); // get first value
            $('#output2').html(res.Two); // get second value
        });
        sayac = sayac + 1;
        if(sayac > 2)
            sayac = 1;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the javascript code like this:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#klikme').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sayac.php',
        data: 'komut='+sayac,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
        $('#output').html(result.One);
        $('#output2').html(result.Two);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: your code is correct but , what is the issue using `$.post`. this is latest and fast than `$.ajax`.